# Calculate $\prod_{n=2}^\infty\bigg(1-\frac1{n^2}\bigg)$

Tags: products

How do you compute $\prod_{n=2}^\infty\bigg(1-\frac1{n^2}\bigg)$

I have no clue on how to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint**.  This may be seen as a [telescoping product](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/m/Algebra/TelescopingSums.shtml) using
$$
1-\frac1{n^2}=\frac{n-1}{n} \cdot \frac{n+1}{n}, \qquad n\ge2.
$$ Hope you can finish it.